# Как добавить собранную из исходников библиотеку boost в qt creator на linux

Tags: c++, linux, qtcreator, boost

Я собрал из исходников библиотеку буст с помощью скриптов, которые шли с исходниками(ниже команды которые я прописывал)

> /bootstrap.sh --prefix=/libs
>
> ./b2 install

После сборки в директории libs появилось 2 новые директории, include и lib соответственно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я прописал в pro файле qt creatora путь к boost

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += I-/libs/include/boost

LIBS += -L/libs/lib
```

По идее, я указал путь и к хедерам(include/boost) и к бинарникам (lib), но тем не менее, при попытке скомпилировать тестовый код, я получаю набор ошибок. Как правильно прописать pro файл на линуксе, где я ошибся?
(набор ошибок)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно указать не только папку с либами, но и конкретные либы, которые нужно подключать.

Comment: @Chorkov, этой файлы внутри библиотеки lib .so или .a ?

Comment: Я всегда подключаю не в ручную, а посредством опций среды: ПКМ на проекте в дереве каталогов в среде -> Добавить библиотеку... -> Внешняя -> Далее. В поле "Файл библиотеки" указываем путь к .so или .a (путь к хэдерам будет определён автоматически). Нажимаем "Далее". Попробуйте. Возможно, описал не очень подробно, но буду рад уточнить, если что-то не понятно.